# how to get position of path?

Tags: android, path, ondraw

i'm making a drawing application.

i have several shapes on the screen like rectangle, circle, heart, line.
i want to make a pattern background with that kind of shapes.

if user chooes circle background my photo is drawn following on the circle path in the background.

first i have to draw the background shape of circle or whatever.
so i think i have a chance to save coordinates of path during drawing the background shape.
but i have no idea how to get coordinates during drawing the shape.

if i have array of coordinates of path, i think i can position my photo image following the path.

and i have tomove shape images following the bg path too.

i need to get coordinates from certain path that i drawing.

could anybody help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, i found the answer myself.

PathMeasure and matrix is the solution.

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg14567.html